# How to create a multirow latex table with line on main diagonal?

Tags: tables, line, diagbox

I would like to create a Latex table with a line on the main diagonal. My problem: diagbox does not calculate the height in the right way for multirow fields. A small example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{\textwidth*1/7}*{3}{|p{\textwidth*1/7}}}
\diagbox[innerwidth=\textwidth*1/7]{from}{to} & item1 & item2 & item3 \\\hline
item1 & \diagbox[innerwidth=\textwidth*1/7]{~}{~} & --- this --- is --- a --- very --- long --- multirow --- text --- & \\\hline
item2 & & \diagbox[innerwidth=\textwidth*1/7]{~}{~} &   \\\hline
item3 & & & \diagbox[innerwidth=\textwidth*1/7]{~}{~}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: diagbox and multirow]

How can I connect the diagonal lines?

Greeting, Patrick

Comment: Is the diagonal to be straight all over the table or only on the single cells?

Comment: The diagonal should be straigt only on the single cells.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why if you use `height=...` option of `\diagbox` the text of the following multiline cell is shifted down, but you can work around it adding a `\vspace{-...}` to bring it up again.

However, I suggest to you to redesign your table with no vertical rules, no diagonal boxes, and em-dashes as text of the cells on the diagonal.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}
\noindent With a little workaround:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{p{\textwidth*1/7}*{3}{|p{\textwidth*1/7}}}
        \diagbox[innerwidth=\textwidth*1/7]{from}{to} & item1 & item2 & item3 \\\hline
        item1 & \diagbox[innerwidth=\textwidth*1/7,height=7\line]{~}{~} & \vspace{-9ex}--- this --- is --- a --- very --- long --- multirow --- text --- & \\\hline
        item2 & & \diagbox[innerwidth=\textwidth*1/7]{~}{~} &   \\\hline
        item3 & & & \diagbox[innerwidth=\textwidth*1/7]{~}{~}
    \end{tabular}   
\end{center}
\noindent But I suggest to you to use something like this:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{p{\textwidth*1/7}}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{To:}\\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
        From: & item1 & item2 & item3 \\
        \midrule
        item1 & \textemdash & --- this --- is --- a --- very --- long --- multirow --- text --- & \\
        item2 & & \textemdash & \\
        item3 & & & \textemdash \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has a built-in command `\diagbox` which always draw the expected diagonal rule (in fact, the rule is drawn with PGF after the construction of the array).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{\textwidth*1/7}*{3}{|p{\textwidth*1/7}}}
\diagbox{from}{to} & item1 & item2 & item3 \\\hline
item1 & \diagbox{}{} & --- this --- is --- a --- very --- long --- multirow --- text --- & \\\hline
item2 & & \diagbox{}{} &   \\\hline
item3 & & & \diagbox{}{}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]